# Why does my Canon Powershot SX400 screen stay white after I turn it on?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, powershot, rear-lcd

After I turn on my Canon Powershot SX400 camera, the screen stays white and nothing I do changes that. What could be the problem and solution?

Comment: When you switch it on, do any lights turn on, and does the lens extend? Does it still take photos, and do they look correct (after downloading to a computer)?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem?

It's broken.

> What could be the solution?

Have it repaired or replace it.